# Cocos2d with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d while using the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, how do you get the pinch coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)handlePinchFrom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    // How to get the coordinates.
    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    // How to get the scale.
    float scale = recognizer.scale;
}
```

... assuming that `self` is your scene.

Comment: Thanks Danyal, this gave me the midpoint of the pinch was hoping for the finger locations any ideas???

Comment: Not sure but one of the answers here discusses it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311197/uipinchgesturerecognizers-touch-locations

Answer (score 0):

There's also some gesture code in CMMSimpleFramework. 
A bit hard to separate - but overall nice work.
https://github.com/kimbobv22/CMMSimpleFramework