# iOS - Pinch to zoom - using CGAffineTransform - to a Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIViewController which is calling a UIView Class, and I'm using CGAffine Transform to zoom into my UIView class instance using the following code

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale,    recognizer.scale);
NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
float scale = recognizer.scale;
float SCALE_MIN = 1.0f;
float SCALE_MAX = 3.0f;
. . .
```

This Basic code, works! (some code has been omitted)

The problem now is regardless of where on the screen I "pinch" the file always zooms from the middle of the file, not at the location as where I am pinching  . .

Any suggestions on how I can get it to zoom into the exact location pinched ?

Comment: for those who are interested Found a great solution to smooth zooming : @Paul Solts Answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150642/max-min-scale-of-pinch-zoom-in-uipinchgesturerecognizer-iphone-ios

Also a similar discussion thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947148/uipinchgesturerecognizer-position-the-pinched-view-between-the-two-fingers

Answer (score 1):

The `locationInView:` method, which is available on all `UIGestureRecognizers`, when called on an instance of `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, will give you the midpoint between the two touches that make up the pinch.  That's the closest thing I think you'll get to "the exact location pinched."

When the gesture is first recognized, save the `locationInView` to get the point at which you want to zoom.  I wouldn't try to update the zoom center during the course of the pinch, because I think you'll end up with a complicated implementation that doesn't behave intuitively.  You'll want the zoom to keep that center point fixed, and you should be able to do that by setting the `anchorPoint` of the `layer` of the view that you're transforming.  Note that `anchorPoint` coordinates are normalized---the default is `(0.5, 0.5)`, the center of the view.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer is it possible for you to give an example on how to change the anchorpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
    lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
}

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
    [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
    const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.2;
    const CGFloat kMinScale = 0.64;

    CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (lastScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
    newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
    newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
    [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

    [gestureRecognizer setScale:1.0];

    lastScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hope this will helpful for you it's work for me like a charm...

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinchRecognizer.view.transform, pinchRecognizer.scale,pinchRecognizer.scale);
    _designImage.transform = transform;
    _Zoomscale = pinchRecognizer.scale;

    NSLog(@"image Pinch scale: %2ff", _Zoomscale);
}
```