# UIImageView shakes in UIPinchGestureRecognizer event

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

I implement pinch operation iOS 8.1 with Swift.
I reference the following links but the image shakes up, down, left and right by little and little.

[UIPinchGestureRecognizer. Make zoom in location of fingers, not only center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245127/uipinchgesturerecognizer-make-zoom-in-location-of-fingers-not-only-center)

[UIPinchGestureRecognizer position the pinched view between the two fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947148/uipinchgesturerecognizer-position-the-pinched-view-between-the-two-fingers)

It is my code in UIViewController and sender.view is UIImageView.

```
func pinchedView(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.numberOfTouches() < 2 {
        return
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        lastScale = 1.0
        lastPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
        return
    }

    let scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - sender.scale)
    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view!.transform, scale, scale)

    let newPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
    var translation = CGPoint()
    translation.x = newPoint.x - lastPoint.x
    translation.y = newPoint.y - lastPoint.y
    sender.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(sender.view!.transform, translation.x, translation.y)

    lastPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
    lastScale = sender.scale
}
```

Why does UIImageView shake?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sender.locationInView(sender.view)
```

try

```
sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView: sender.view)
```

locationInView seems to be picking an undefined touch.